# Youtube API ActivityNotFoundException on Gingerbread

Tags: android, youtube-api

I am getting ActivityNotFoundException error when i am trying to run youtube api StandAlonePlayerActivity on ginger bread. Where as it runs fine on ICS

here is my log cat

```
01-23 15:34:28.071: E/AndroidRuntime(3378): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.google.android.youtube.api.StandalonePlayerActivity.START (has extras) }
01-23 15:34:28.071: E/AndroidRuntime(3378):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1545)
01-23 15:34:28.071: E/AndroidRuntime(3378):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1515)
01-23 15:34:28.071: E/AndroidRuntime(3378):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2988)
01-23 15:34:28.071: E/AndroidRuntime(3378):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:701)
01-23 15:34:28.071: E/AndroidRuntime(3378):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:787)
01-23 15:34:28.071: E/AndroidRuntime(3378):     at com.example.demo.TipsFragment$2.onClick(TipsFragment.java:143)
01-23 15:34:28.071: E/AndroidRuntime(3378):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2533)
01-23 15:34:28.071: E/AndroidRuntime(3378):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9320)
01-23 15:34:28.071: E/AndroidRuntime(3378):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-23 15:34:28.071: E/AndroidRuntime(3378):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-23 15:34:28.071: E/AndroidRuntime(3378):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
01-23 15:34:28.071: E/AndroidRuntime(3378):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4389)
01-23 15:34:28.071: E/AndroidRuntime(3378):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 15:34:28.071: E/AndroidRuntime(3378):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-23 15:34:28.071: E/AndroidRuntime(3378):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
01-23 15:34:28.071: E/AndroidRuntime(3378):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
01-23 15:34:28.071: E/AndroidRuntime(3378):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and here is the code which i have used for starting Player

```
String vid=getYoutubeVideoId(vlink);
Intent intent=YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(getActivity(),DEVELOPER_KEY, vid, 0,true,false);
startActivity(intent);
```

I am getting error on `startActivity`

Here is getYoutubeVideoID() code :

```
/*
     * Getting id of video from url
     */
    public static String getYoutubeVideoId(String youtubeUrl)
    {
        String video_id="";
        if (youtubeUrl != null && youtubeUrl.trim().length() > 0 && youtubeUrl.startsWith("http"))
        {

            String expression = "^.*((youtu.be"+ "\\/)" + "|(v\\/)|(\\/u\\/w\\/)|(embed\\/)|(watch\\?))\\??v?=?([^#\\&\\?]*).*"; // var regExp = /^.*((youtu.be\/)|(v\/)|(\/u\/\w\/)|(embed\/)|(watch\?))\??v?=?([^#\&\?]*).*/;
            CharSequence input = youtubeUrl;
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
            if (matcher.matches())
            {
                String groupIndex1 = matcher.group(7);
                if(groupIndex1!=null && groupIndex1.length()==11)
                    video_id = groupIndex1;
            }
        }
        return video_id;
    }
```

Comment: do u got developer key ?? Can you give me the id of video you are using?? Post the code of getYoutubeVideoId(vlink);

Comment: @edwin yes i have developer key. I mentioned in my question that its running on ICS. I have tried with SimplePlayerView From youtube api

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First check if the youtube service is available on your device, then try to launch that activity.
`YouTubeApiServiceUtil.isYouTubeApiServiceAvailable(mContext)`. Also try installing the youtube app from Google play.

Tiny note from the documentation:
`Note: Users need to run version 4.2.16 of the mobile YouTube app (or higher) to use the API.`

Edit: This is how you use it:

```
if(YouTubeApiServiceUtil.isYouTubeApiServiceAvailable(mContext).equals(YouTubeInitializationResult.SUCCESS)){
   //This means that your device has the Youtube API Service (the app) and you are safe to launch it. 

}else{
   // Log the outcome, take necessary measure, like playing the video in webview :)  
}
```

See the `YouTubeInitializationResult` enums here https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeInitializationResult

Also the philosophy about the aforementioned class:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeApiServiceUtil

Comment: can you paste a snippet for YouTubeApiServiceUtil.isYouTubeApiServiceAvailable(Context context)

Answer (score 1):

The devices should have the latest YouTube app installed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the app on the emulator? It might not work on the emulator as youtube player is not installed by default. Try running it on an actual device.

Comment: i am running it on Htc explorer

Comment: is the Youtube app installed in your device?

Comment: did u try upgrading the player?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use [**YouTube api**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/) for android you need 3 Parameters

1) YouTube [**Developer Key**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol)

2)Video Id

3)Latest official [**YouTube Android App**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.youtube&hl=en) (version 4.2.16)

By looking on you log cat i think one among this is missing

[**Refer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229708/is-android-youtube-api-using-official-youtube-app-for-playing-video)

Comment: its running fine on Ics. I have downloaded Latest version of youtube api from [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/)

Comment: ok, i tested the demo app on Android 2.1 ,it works fine for me   .. youtube api need latest version of youtube official app for playing video . is your youtube app in phone is latest version ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to install YouTube Android App  on your device, it's worked for me !

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest some improvements to @Nikola answer. It's possible to show localised dialog [getErrorDialog()](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeInitializationResult#public-dialog-geterrordialog-activity-activity-int-requestcode) to handle some user-recoverable errors [isUserRecoverableError](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeInitializationResult#isUserRecoverableError()). For example, when YouTube app is disabled in Settings.

```
val result = YouTubeApiServiceUtil.isYouTubeApiServiceAvailable(context)
when {
    result == YouTubeInitializationResult.SUCCESS -> startYouTubeActivity()
    result.isUserRecoverableError -> result.getErrorDialog(activity, 0).show()
    else -> toast("Something went wrong!")
}
```