# issues running video in Android

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-videoview, mediacontroller

I'm currently working in my Android app. and so far I got to the point where I need my app. to view some videos for the user 
initially I thought of storing my videos in my server (currently is local but might move it later) and then I did not find a way how to do it so I choose to load it from a YouTube channel I made  it for that purpose "I thought It'd look more porf." any way!!!

So far I run my app. in my phone coz I read that Emulator is not capable of running videos. It runs in my phone but with some issues.

1- I have to pause the video ASA the video layout pops up and wait for the video to buffer or something like that otherwise I got error msg "this video can't be played"

2- later when it loads it starts by it self even I did not press the start button.
3- the video is taking the top half of the screen leaving the bottom have a in White space with gap between the two halves.

4- the video is not clear as I can view it in my laptop or in YouTube app.

here is my .java code

```
public class video extends Activity {


String SrcPath = "rtsp://v8.cache3.c.youtube.com/CjYLENy73wIaLQltaP8vg4qMsBMYDSANFEIJbXYtZ29vZ2xlSARSBXdhdGNoYOL6qv2DoMPrUAw=/0/0/0/video.3gp";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.video1);
VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.vview);
myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(SrcPath));
myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
myVideoView.requestFocus();
myVideoView.start();
}}
```

I really want some helps from you ppl.

any help is appreciated dudes.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to play video only during a button press. There are two approaches

1) Remove `myVideoView.start();` form the code ,i think it will stop playing of video on load

2)Next approach is do not set default `MediaController`for video view

you can create custom play button for playing video and give `myVideoView.start();` inside it's onclick

```
Button play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
play .setOnClickListener(this);
Button pause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPause);
pause .setOnClickListener(this);
Button stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
stop .setOnClickListener(this);
public void onClick(View v) {
switch(v.getId()){
case R.id.btnPlay:
     myVideoView.start();
    /*  the instruccions of the button */
    break;
case R.id.btnPause:
    /*  the instruccions of the button */
    break;
case R.id.btnStop:
      myVideoView.stop();
    /*  the instruccions of the button */
    break;
  }
}
```

And the thing  about clarity of video you are playing `rtsp` link which got low quality video eve you can see in link itselp you can see `.3gp` extension which is low quality

If you want to improve the quality . Have an eye on this
[**YouTube api**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/)

[REFER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14477447/1450401)

Comment: for the video auto play solved by removing the .start()  thanx a lot buddy