# Unable to start activity - YouTubeStandalonePlayer

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I am trying to use YouTubeStandalonePlayer from https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeStandalonePlayer

With this code inside `onCreate()`:

```
Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(this, DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, VIDEO_ID);
startActivity(intent);
```

But application fails with error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.youtubestandalone/com.example.youtubestandalone.MainActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.google.android.youtube.api.StandalonePlayerActivity.START (has extras) }
```

How to fix this?

Comment: have you define this activity in Manifest.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
            android:name="com.google.android.youtube.api.StandalonePlayerActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
 />
```

Comment: You should actually check to see if Youtube is available on the phone as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14477843/396005 Adding the activity to your manifest won't help

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have include the jar file in your project. Make sure you have done the follow steps.

1. Right Click your project
2. Select Properties
3. Select Java Build Path
4. Go to Order and Export Tab
5. Tick YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi

Good luck!