# Android: WebView compatibility (Chromium and WebKit WebView)

Tags: android, webview

If I want to support the Chromium WebView, I set minimum required SDK to API 19: Android 4.4 (KitKat). Works fine.

But if I set the SDK to API 16 Android 4.1, I can support more devices via the old WebKit WebView.

My question is, if I set it to API 16, will users who are running Android 4.4+ see the Chromium WebView or will they be stuck with the old WebView?

Comment: Interesting question. I'm iOS developer so not very informed, but I'm guessing (hoping) that Android 4.4 or above will auto use the chromium webview.

Comment: Nice article which clears all the doubts regarding Chromium integration - http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/android-4-4-kitkat-browser-chrome-webview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Users, who will running Android 4.4+ will see the Chromium WebView only.
There is no "old" or "new" WebView in Android - only current version, which depends on OS version.
For more details, read: https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html

Comment: Thank you. Is there any info on which of these versions work with sites that embed youtube videos via HTML5 (or iframe for that matter)?

Comment: Can't tell you exactly, but I can give you some useful links for you: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156411/loading-youtube-video-through-i-frame-in-android-webview