# Android how to pass url in android iframe webview?

Tags: java, android, iframe, webview

Android how to pass url in android `iframe` `webview`?
I'm trying to pass url dynamically form server so what i do

```
if(ResponseProduct.video!=null) {

                            String html = "<iframe width=\"450\" height=\"260\" src=\""+ResponseProduct.video+"\" ></iframe>";
                            WebView webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.video);
                            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
                            webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
                            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
                            webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
                            webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
                            webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
                            webView.loadData(html, "text/html; video/mpeg", "UTF-8");

                        }
```

Comment: what is ResponseProduct.video? is it video file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put `String` url path in `src` like :

```
 String videoPath="http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/31592/charts/1?width=450&height=260&results=60&dynamic=true\\";

 String html = "<iframe width=\"450\" height=\"260\" style=\"border: 1px solid #cccccc;\" src=\""+videoPath+" ></iframe>";
```

if videoUrl is null or  not valid then your page is not load then you need to hide webView

Here is code :

```
private boolean isValidUrl(String url) {
      Pattern p = Patterns.WEB_URL;
      Matcher m = p.matcher(url.toLowerCase());
      if(m.matches())
         return true;
      else
        return false;
}
```

then after load it into `webView`

```
 webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
if(videoPath!=null && isValidUrl(videoPath)
{
mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
webview.loadData(html, "text/html", null);
    }

else
webview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: this error  ----  @AD 10 W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/evrc
                     Unsupported mime audio/qcelp
W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/qcelp
                     Unsupported mime audio/evrc
W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/mpeg2
                     Unsupported mime video/mpeg2

Comment: try with this
 webView.loadData(html, "text/html", "UTF-8");

and can you please provide video url?

Comment: refer  this may helps -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156411/loading-youtube-video-through-i-frame-in-android-webview

Comment: how to change visibility of webview in android  webView.setVisibility(View.GONE); this is not orkin its still carving space of screen

Comment: webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: okay tell me, when you want to hide webview? on button click? and post your whole class code

Comment: i am getting the url from server so when the url is null then do that

Comment: is that work  if(ResponseProduct.video!=null && isValidUrl(ResponseProduct.video))

Comment: did you check url is valid or not ?