# Why iframe wont load on Android studio?

Tags: javascript, java, android, html, iframe

when i want to load webpage, everything works well except iframe, he wont load youtube video...
html code is

```
<div class="td-module-meta-info">
  <h4>
    <strong></strong>
  </h4>
  <p>
    <iframe class=" lazyloaded" 
      data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/MTiojrD_tls" 
      width="100%" height="392" frameborder="0" 
      allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" data-mce-fragment="1">
    </iframe>
  </p>
</div>
```

so basic code just wont load video...

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            WebSettings ws=myWebView.getSettings();
            ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            ws.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
myWebView.load("<div class="td-module-meta-info"><h4><strong</strong></h4><p><iframe class=" lazyloaded" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/MTiojrD_tls" width="100%" height="392" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" data-mce-fragment="1"></iframe></p></div>")
```

Why its happend? Should i add something in WebSettings?

Comment: Try adding `src` in place of `data-src`

Comment: Thanks, thats works, so when I load page should just replace this somehow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loading Youtube video through iframe in Android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156411/loading-youtube-video-through-iframe-in-android-webview)